# Is it possible to execute a WF field update action from another WF time trigger action

Tags: workflow

I have WF time trigger action (1) which updates a boolean field as True based on a certain criteria. 
The field update action is `Locked__c = True`

I have configured another (2) WF field update action which should update the RecordType if

```
Obj: Record Type EQUALS 'Meeting' AND  Obj: Locked__c = True
```

then

```
Obj: Record Type = 'Completed'
```

WF Rule(1) and Time Trigger Action is working expectedly and Locked__c becomes True

But WF Rule (2) is not firing.

Is making `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change`true or writing a trigger only option here ? Due to some reason WF Rule(2) is not firing, is it expected behavior that a WF Rule Action can't fire another WF Rule Action until `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change` is true.

Comment: yes, You need to set `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change` to true

Comment: @TusharSharma Please put your comment as an answer so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, You need to set Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change to true.
You don't need trigger for this. This will solve your problem.